# Why does this functions not work?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code:

```
p1 = "Hey"
p2 = "Hey2"
p3 = "Hey3"
p4 = "Hey4"
p5 = "Hey5"

def ifdisplaygrid(x1,x2,x3):
    x1 += "Y"
    x2 += "N"
    x3 += "K"
    if x1 == p3 and x2 == p4 and x3 == p5:
        print p1 + p2 + x1 + x2 + x3
    else:
        print "Function Is Not Working!!!"
ifdisplaygrid(p3,p4,p5)
```

I want it the output to be:

```
HeyHey2Hey3YHey4NHey5K
```

But that never happens, what am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Remove the three first lines of the ifdisplaygrid method - edit: for your specific case you should move them below the if statement, but you should be able to see what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters to the function are copied by value type, so when you change x1-x3 the original variables don't change. Thus the if-statement is false.

Comment: so do i get them to change?

Answer (score 1):

Before your if condition check, you have already modified the value of x1, x2 and x3, hence it will never be equal to p3, p4 and p5. Adding that concatination logic inside the if condition will make your code work

```
def ifdisplaygrid(x1,x2,x3):
if x1 == p3 and x2 == p4 and x3 == p5:
x1 += "Y"
x2 += "N"
x3 += "K"   
    print p1 + p2 + x1 + x2 + x3
else:
    print "Function Is Not Working!!!"
```

Comment: What i was trying to do was chcek if p1 is in the space of x1

Comment: But in your code snippet, there is no code having conditions between p1 and x1. if it is with p3, then instead of x1 == p3, you might need to try something like x1 contains p3, etc